# google map not showing on the page which is a jsp and it redirects from another jsp page

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I want to display google map on button click which will redirect to another jsp page. Now what happens that while another page comes up and when i clicked button to display map, it is not coming but that div took place in the page.
 Also when i run that file only it is working. I am using netbeans ide.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

        </script>

        <script>
            function initializemap()
            {
                var mapProp123 = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map123 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap123")
                        , mapProp123);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>I Am Now A Mobile Developer!!</p>
                <input type="button" value="get map" onclick="initializemap()();">
                <div id="googleMap123" style="height: 300px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;"></div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h1>Footer Text</h1>
            </div>
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: anyone can help me than i can talk in detail...????

Comment: `onclick="initializemap();"`